# Do subscriptions work with singleValueExtendedProperties?

Tags: rest, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for a way to use Graph API's for syncing calendar events. Example different types of meeting requests such as "Case Events(court cases) meetings, corporate meetings , persons meetings. For this case in particular he would like to get an event notification when If someone tried to delete a "Case Event Meeting" and prevent the delete.

We have a Java application that adds the different type of meeting requests to the calendar and all of those have an event origin of {f19d3c30-0660-4f7f-96df-6dc78a686633}

The follow code works fine for a changeType  of Created, Accepted

```
    "subscriptionConfiguration": {
      "changeType": "Created,Accepted,Deleted",
      "notificationUrl": "https://xxxxx/listen",
      "resource": "me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {XXYY1231-0660-5ty5-96df-6brca687744} Name event_origin' and ep/value eq null)",
    .... },
```

The code above returns nothing in the case of **changeType = delete**

The only reason they are using the "singleValueExtendedProperties" filter only because they want to filter out only calls created from there java application and act upon them. It works fine for "changeType": "Created,Accepted", but Deleted it returns nothing as the filter seems to remove them.

Is there another way we could filter out the requests that would not require the use the "singleValueExtendedProperties" filter?

Can we think of other options to that would be better than the workaround above?

Answer (score 0):

While you should be able to get notified about the delete, both sync and notifications are "after the fact", so there would be no way to prevent the delete.  The closest you could get is to recreate the event which would of course require you to have an offline copy of the event so you could recreate it.